# В bootstrap 3 col-md не правильно налезает на блоки

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">    
</div>
```

Блоки не заполняют свободное пространство, нарисовал на схеме как они располагаются, охото чтобы этих пустых полей не было, не пойму в чем проблема. Пожалуйста, помогите) Причем это в левом столбце только пустые места, в правом столбце таких нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю у меня кострукция должны быть

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

А у меня сейчас

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Проблема решена, всем спасибо кто не остался равнодушным))

Comment: код покажите свой

Comment: вы без js наверное и не сделаете иначе

Comment: <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">    
</div></div>

Comment: Да да вы забыли добавить внутри блока .row